# CORS header not applied for a particular route in Express cloud functions

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, cors, preflight

I implemented a basic express app for cloud functions. I have used the cors library to enable cors. There are 4 api endpoints and all 4 need to be preflighted. For some reason, `access-control-allow-origin:*` header is placed on the 3 routes and not the 4th one.
Precisely, i'm using Content-Type: application/json for POST requests, which need to be preflighted. All the endpoints need the same headers, but it isn't applied for the last one.

Code snippets:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/', require('./controllers'));

exports.apiv2 = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.use('/create-player', require('./createPlayer'));
router.use('/create-game', require('./createGame'));
router.use('/join-game', require('./joinGame'));
router.use('/move', require('./makeMove'));

// 404 error handler for invalid player and game IDs
router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.json({ error: err.msg });
});


module.exports = router;
```

For the /move route alone, the cors request fails, even after preflight request passes. [Preflight passes with 204](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEp5z.png). The actual request fails for some reason. [The POST request fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glHjb.png)

Is there any particular access control header is not placed by express for one endpoint alone ?

Answer (score -1):

You can set this middleware before your routes middleware in `app.js` to solve thi problem:

```js
// app.js

...

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method)
    res.sendStatus(200);
  else
    next();
});

...

app.use(routes);
```

Then, this will be applied for all of your routes.

Comment: `cors` is already used in the code. it basically does the same.